# Django form.clean(), cleaned_data KeyError

Tags: django, forms

In [Django 1.4 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/), it says that `clean_<fieldname>` methods are run first, then form `clean` method is executed.

I have the following code sample. The form is used with FormPreview. When `pmid` field is empty in the form, it should throw `ValidationError` exception, but it doesn't happen.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    pmid = forms.CharField()
    .. other fields ..

    def clean(self):
        cd = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        cd['pmid'] # returns KeyError and it's not in cd
        return cd
```

I don't override any `clean_<field>` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if all you want to do is ensure a field is not blank, then just add `required=True` to it. For example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    pmid = forms.CharField(required=True)
    ...
```

And you're done.

However, even if you couldn't do it that way, you *still* wouldn't validate it in `clean`, but in `clean_<fieldname>` as the docs describe.

```
def clean_pmid(self):
    pmid = self.cleaned_data.get('pmid')
    if not pmid:
        raise forms.ValidationError('pmid cannot be blank')
    return pmid
```

Comment: Default value of required is True. Also, as far as I know, even if `clean_<field>` is not overriden, it still checks if the field is empty or not.

Comment: When you say "empty" do you really mean "doesn't even exist in the form"?

Comment: No, it exists in the form, but not filled. My problem might be related to FormPreview.

Comment: Empty/not filled/blank/etc. fields will still have a key in `cleaned_data`. It's value will merely be `None` or an empty string (`''`). If you're getting a `KeyError` that means the field was *not* posted with form, as if it wasn't even on the page.

Comment: I solved it. For FormPreview, I'm using two templates and in the second one, the template doesn't have fields. Django tries to build form from post data, but since data is not available, form from posted data is not created properly. In other words, I'm using template [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/formtools/templates/formtools/preview.html) but without lines 19-20. Thanks Chris, for help.